# How do I connect multiple characteristics at the same time?

Tags: android, rx-java, rxandroidble

I am trying to read and write in/from characteristic of particular service of BLE device.

I am referring demo code from [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) here.

In this demo as soon as discover services when you press particular characteristic it go in next screen and make connection and then doing read/write operation.

My question: is there any way to read/write any characteristics after service discovered? Why you need to make connection for with any characteristics before read/write operation?

Below code is used to connect single characteristic but i want to connect 3-4 characteristics at the same time. i tried **.flatmap()** but giving me errors.

```
  final Disposable connectionDisposable = connectionObservable
                            .flatMapSingle(RxBleConnection::discoverServices)
                            .flatMapSingle(rxBleDeviceServices -> rxBleDeviceServices.getCharacteristic(Consts.ALERT_LEVEL_UUID))
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> text_connection.setText("Status: Connecting"))
                            .subscribe(
                                    characteristic -> {
                                        updateUI(characteristic);
                                        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Hey, connection has been established!");
                                    },
                                    this::onConnectionFailure,
                                    this::onConnectionReceived
                            );
```

Like in below image as soon as you press R or W for any characteristic it will give you result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got work around.

**For connection**

```
 Disposable disposable = connectionObservable
                            .flatMap(connection -> connection.discoverServices()
                                            .map(RxBleDeviceServices::getBluetoothGattServices)
                                            .flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable) // map to individual services
                                            .map(BluetoothGattService::getCharacteristics) // for each service take all characteristics)
                                            .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable) // map to individual characteristic)
                                    //.filter(characteristic -> (BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE) != 0) // consider only characteristics that have indicate or notify property

                            )
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(
                                    characteristic -> {
                                        onConnectionReceived();
                               },
                                    this::onConnectionFailure,
                                    this::onConnectionReceived
                            );

                    compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
```

If connection successful then you can read, write and notify any characteristics in this single connection

For read, write and notifications you can check [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you might want to look into sharing the BLE connection using Jake Wharton's [ReplayingShare](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare).

Here is some discussion of it that might help: https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/406

Reactive purists seem to believe that you should be able to do anything you want with a single `subscribe()` statement, but I'm not smart enough to figure that out.